# Config Package Issue Deploying Node.js App on Vercel - "Configuration property not defined" Error

Tags: node.js, vercel

I'm using the config package in Node.js to organize all my environment variables, and it works perfectly in my local environment. However, when I deploy the app to Vercel, I encounter the following error:

> WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names. WARNING: See
> https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode WARNING:
> No configurations found in configuration directory:/var/task/config
> WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the
> environment. Error: Configuration property "logging.level" is not
> defined
> at Config.get (/var/task/server/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:179:11)
> at Object. (/var/task/server/logger/index.js:5:22)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
> at t..e._load (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:2299)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
> at Object. (/var/task/server/index.js:8:16) INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 716.96 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type:
> Runtime.ExitError Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
> Runtime.ExitError The configuration files are located in the ./config
> folder: development.json, production.json, and default.json. Details
> about the app are provided below:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "My app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "hhh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "config": "^3.3.8",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.7.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongodb": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.3",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

**vercel.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

**./config/default.json**

```
{
  "logging": {
    "level": "info",
    "trace": true
  }
}
```

Now, from the app:

```
const config = require("config");
const level = config.get("logging.level"); // ERROR
```

I also tried setting the environment variable NODE_CONFIG_DIR='./config', still not working . Please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below two line before using config:

```
const express = require('express');
process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR'] = path.join(path.resolve("./"),"config/")
```